# How can I get the Windows version number from .NET?

Tags: .net, windowsversion

I'm using a virtualized web server and I don't remember whether it's running Windows Server 2000 or 2003.  How can I tell which?

Ask the ISP, course, which I did.  The question, then, is somewhat academic.  Is there any way to tell this from .NET?

I access the machine through Plesk, which is designed to shield you from this kind of arcana.

*Why* do I want to know this?  Because I'm getting ready to install a product that is supported on 2003 but not 2000.  (I know this doesn't mean it won't run.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve this from [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx).

Comment: Thank you... it just hit me after I posted.  I was looking for Environment.WindowsVersion, not expecting them to be platform-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving version information from `System.Environment.OSVersion` remember that [checking file versions is surprisingly hard](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2009/03/05/checking-file-versions-is-surprisingly-hard.aspx).

Comment: Good tip.  The answer I got was **Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2**, which, after a little searching, I learned corresponds to Server 2003... or Windows XP 64-bit Edition (IA-64)... or Windows XP Professional x64 Edition.  I just took a wild guess.